# Looping through a List

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach

Ok, i have a class which is as follows:

```
public class MT101
    {

        // Sequence A
        public string tag20 { get; set; }  // 16x
        public string tag21R { get; set; } // 16x
        public string tag28D { get; set; } // 16x
        public List<String> tag50;         // Option F, G, H, C, or L
      }
```

i then have a method, which make a new instance of said class as follows:

```
    public class CheckMessage
    {
        private List<MT101> Message101 = new List<MT101>();
        public List<MT101> CheckMt101Message(string[] messageBody)
        {
            MT101 buildMessage = new MT101();
            .
            .
            . perform all the neccessary logic to add into buildMessage and then return the
            . Message101 object
            Message101.Add(buildMessage);
            return Message101;
        }
     }
```

I call the Method from another class as such:

```
  GlobalClasses.CheckMessage gm = new GlobalClasses.CheckMessage();
```

and pass in the variables as such:

```
  string[] _block4 = Regex.Split(trimmed, @"\r\n");
  gm.CheckMt101Message(_block4);

        foreach (GlobalClasses.CheckMessage item in gm)
        { }
```

In visual studio, i get the following errors when compiled:

Error 1 GlobalClasses.MT101.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()': containing type does not implement interface 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Error 2 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GlobalClasses.CheckMessage' because 'SASMI.GlobalClasses.CheckMessage' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I've googled and found reference to setting IEnumerable to the class, so 'ive tried this:

public class Mt101 : IEnumberable

same message being reported.

Comment: What collection/list are you attempting to iterate over??

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Your `foreach` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `CheckMessage`  is not an `IEnumerable`

Comment: gm is a class and not a list, I do not even know where to begin you really need to re-think this.

Comment: problem is here `foreach (GlobalClasses.CheckMessage item in gm)`

Comment: What was the question? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to iterate over the `MT101` objects in the `Message101` field in the class. The easiest way to accomplish this, is to make `Message101` public, e.g.:

```
public class CheckMessage
{
    private List<MT101> message101 = new List<MT101>();

    public List<MT101> Messge101 { get { return message101; } }

    public List<MT101> CheckMt101Message(string[] messageBody)
    {
        MT101 buildMessage = new MT101();
        .
        .
        . perform all the neccessary logic to add into buildMessage and then return the
        . Message101 object
        Message101.Add(buildMessage);
        return Message101;
    }
}
```

And then you can iterate over these objects:

```
foreach (MT101 item in gm.Message101)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The item type in the `foreach` should be `MT101`, not `GlobalClasses.CheckMessage` or just `var`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that one :).

Comment: Cheers Pieter, that sorted it

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the return value of `CheckMt101Message` and instead try to iterate on the class itself. That won't work. Save the return value and iterate over it:

```
var messages = gm.CheckMt101Message(_block4);

foreach (Mt101 item in messages)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the procedures to iterate through the loop

```
EMP oeemp= new EMP();
            List<EMP> tr= new List<EMP>();
            foreach(var t in tr)
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate on the internal List using the reference to the class CheckMessage then you need to implement a function that returns an IEnumerator like this

in CheckMessage class

```
    public IEnumerator<MT101> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (MT101 m in this.Message101)
        {
             yield return m;
        }
    }
```

in your code

```
  foreach(MT101 m in gm)
  {
      .....
  }
```

Of course you could execute the foreach also on the return value of CheckMt101Message but the [yield keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) allows a couple of advantages. You need to have just the reference to the CheckMessage class, you don't need to make your internal list public, you could execute the loop at any moment using only the CheckMessage reference and you could add custom code before and after the yeld.

Comment: Hi Steve, can't accept two amswers otherwise this would get a tick also.

Comment: It is your choice, no problem. I stand behind my answer because I think it produces a better code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
foreach (MT101 item in gm.CheckMt101Message(_block4)) { ... }
```

I'm afraid you have a big confusion so I recommend you to check yourself about why your code is not working, this would be much more helpful for you than just copy paste any of provided solutions.

Comment: This also works. However, this requires you to add a block to be able to iterate it. If you just copy the result of `CheckMt101Message` to a variable, you don't have to add a block to be able to iterate over the list.

Comment: Ok, so a lot of responses on this one. Pieter, your correct that I want to iterate over the class. My line of thought was that I could build up an object, which either cotained singe strings or list of strings. I then need to loop through each an perform further checkes on them.